# Trigger can not catch when insert data to table while using file

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's the table

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(0,1),
    Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Surname NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(30), 
    Facebook NVARCHAR(30),

    CHECK(Email IS NOT NULL OR Facebook IS NOT NULL)
);
```

This is the data which i have to insert these to `Users` table.

```
1, N'Alex', Mituchin, qwe@gmail.com, NULL
```

This is `BULK INSERT`

```
BULK INSERT Users
FROM 'C:\Users\SAMIR\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\users.txt'
WITH (
      FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
     --FIRSTROW = 0,
     --UTF-8
     CODEPAGE = '65001',
     DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'
);
```

And finally this is the trigger which has to filter the data when data inserted to `Users` table

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertedUsersTB
ON Users
AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE Users
    SET NAME = (CASE 
                   WHEN NAME LIKE 'N''%'''
                      THEN SUBSTRING(Name, 3, LEN(Name) - 3)
                      ELSE NAME
                END)
    FROM Users
```

The problem is when I bulk insert into my `Users` table, the trigger can not catch this. How can I do that trigger start the work?

Comment: Based on your 2 posts for the day, I can tell you right now you're creating a huge mess for yourself. Take a step back and start this process over from the beginning now that you understand the pitfalls. Don't use triggers to cleanse data.

Comment: @JacobH what i have to use instead of trigger?

Comment: Can you not perhaps load the data into a 'staging post' table and then do the cleansing there (after the bulk insert is finished) before populating your production table? Completely agree with @JacobH that you are over-complicating this.

Comment: Also: it's very odd that your `AFTER INSERT` trigger isn't consulting the `Inserted` pseudo table at all. This is the pseudo table available inside the trigger only, that contains all the rows that have been inserted by the last statement - one will typically use that pseudo table to determine which rows to do something to - not just the whole table!

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql), you could find out that it doesn't fire triggers by default. You need to add the option on your statement. The option is simply `FIRE_TRIGGERS`

Comment: @SamirHemzeyev I think this may have answered the question, but I'm not sure that it really solved the problem.

Comment: I have to agree with Shawn. This would be far more efficient with the solution I proposed on the other question posted by Samir.